# AKS LoadBalancer service creating spurious network traffic

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

I’m attempting to deploy an SFTP server using python / paramiko into AKS.

This deployed successfully into a bare metal dev server, however I am having issues deploying this into AKS.

The problem starts when creating the LoadBalancer service, this triggers a deluge of TCP traffic on the target port which renders the SFTP server useless.

Is this expected? I’m at the limit of how the AKS internals work so I don’t want to assume this is an error, but I would like to know where I might be going wrong.

The code below reproduces the issue in a newly provisioned AKS environment using the `nast` network sniffer. Run the first command to launch nast and then create the load balancer service using in a separate console:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never --image=ubuntu --labels="app=debug-pod" debug-pod -- bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y nast && nast"

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: debug-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: debug-pod 
  ports:
  - name: sftp
    protocol: TCP
    port: 34567
    targetPort: 45678
EOF
```

Sample traffic seen ~10 seconds after the LoadBalancer is created at a rate of several every second:

```
Nast V. 0.2.0

Sniffing on:

- Device:       eth0
- MAC address:  66:4E:3B:41:F3:7B
- IP address:   10.244.0.61
- Netmask:      255.255.255.0
- Promisc mode: Set
- Filter:       None
- Logging:      None

---[ ARP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
2A:8E:A8:C9:D3:1E -> 66:4E:3B:41:F3:7B
Type: ARP request: Who has 10.244.0.61? Tell 10.244.0.1
Hardware size: 6 - Protocol size: 4
Packet Number: 1

---[ ARP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
66:4E:3B:41:F3:7B -> 2A:8E:A8:C9:D3:1E
Type: ARP reply: 10.244.0.61 is at 66:4E:3B:41:F3:7B
Hardware size: 6 - Protocol size: 4
Packet Number: 2

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.240.0.7:64618(unknown) -> 10.244.0.61:45678(unknown)
TTL: 126        Window: 8192    Version: 4      Length: 52
FLAGS: -S-----  SEQ: 2330618374 - ACK: 0
Packet Number: 5

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.244.0.61:45678(unknown) -> 10.240.0.7:64618(unknown)
TTL: 64         Window: 0       Version: 4      Length: 40
FLAGS: --R-A--  SEQ: 0 - ACK: 2330618375
Packet Number: 6

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.240.0.7:31026(unknown) -> 10.244.0.61:45678(unknown)
TTL: 126        Window: 8192    Version: 4      Length: 52
FLAGS: -S-----  SEQ: 2330618374 - ACK: 0
Packet Number: 7

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.244.0.61:45678(unknown) -> 10.240.0.7:31026(unknown)
TTL: 64         Window: 0       Version: 4      Length: 40
FLAGS: --R-A--  SEQ: 0 - ACK: 2330618375
Packet Number: 8

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.240.0.7:52540(unknown) -> 10.244.0.61:45678(unknown)
TTL: 126        Window: 8192    Version: 4      Length: 48
FLAGS: -S-----  SEQ: 2330618374 - ACK: 0
Packet Number: 9

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.244.0.61:45678(unknown) -> 10.240.0.7:52540(unknown)
TTL: 64         Window: 0       Version: 4      Length: 40
FLAGS: --R-A--  SEQ: 0 - ACK: 2330618375
Packet Number: 10

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.240.0.6:32242(unknown) -> 10.244.0.61:45678(unknown)
TTL: 126        Window: 8192    Version: 4      Length: 52
FLAGS: -S-----  SEQ: 2102210393 - ACK: 0
Packet Number: 11

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.244.0.61:45678(unknown) -> 10.240.0.6:32242(unknown)
TTL: 64         Window: 0       Version: 4      Length: 40
FLAGS: --R-A--  SEQ: 0 - ACK: 2102210394
Packet Number: 12

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.240.0.6:27550(unknown) -> 10.244.0.61:45678(unknown)
TTL: 126        Window: 8192    Version: 4      Length: 52
FLAGS: -S-----  SEQ: 2102210393 - ACK: 0
Packet Number: 13

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.244.0.61:45678(unknown) -> 10.240.0.6:27550(unknown)
TTL: 64         Window: 0       Version: 4      Length: 40
FLAGS: --R-A--  SEQ: 0 - ACK: 2102210394
Packet Number: 14

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.240.0.6:65391(unknown) -> 10.244.0.61:45678(unknown)
TTL: 126        Window: 8192    Version: 4      Length: 48
FLAGS: -S-----  SEQ: 2102210393 - ACK: 0
Packet Number: 15

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.244.0.61:45678(unknown) -> 10.240.0.6:65391(unknown)
TTL: 64         Window: 0       Version: 4      Length: 40
FLAGS: --R-A--  SEQ: 0 - ACK: 2102210394
Packet Number: 16

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.240.0.7:18224(unknown) -> 10.244.0.61:45678(unknown)
TTL: 126        Window: 8192    Version: 4      Length: 52
FLAGS: -S-----  SEQ: 2517447963 - ACK: 0
Packet Number: 17

---[ TCP ]-----------------------------------------------------------
10.244.0.61:45678(unknown) -> 10.240.0.7:18224(unknown)
TTL: 64         Window: 0       Version: 4      Length: 40
FLAGS: --R-A--  SEQ: 0 - ACK: 2517447964
Packet Number: 18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by setting `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` in the LoadBalancer service, rather than the default value of `Cluster`.

Answer (score 2):

The host at 10.240.0.7 is trying to connect to IP 10.240.0.7 port 45678. That host reports that the port is not open. The process repeats.

**Your problem is that there is no process listening on port 45678.**

Comment: Thanks. I have some follow-up questions. 10.240.0.7 is the IP address of one of the cluster nodes. I'm curious why a node is trying to communicate via this service as I'm not expecting it to. Also why would this happen on AKS and not on my bare metal cluster?

Comment: @BellyBuster - From the information in your question, I cannot answer why the traffic is occurring. You have a process that is trying to connect on port 45678 but nothing is listening for those connection attempts.